# C++ Image Processing: Uniform Smoothing Operation Makes Image Darker

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, smoothing, noise-reduction

I'm trying to reduce noise in an image by creating a 2D uniform smoothing algorithm in C++. The function I'm using for each pixel computes the average value of neighboring pixels within a square odd window and uses that as the new value.

Whenever I run the code, however, the pixels in the new image become darker (a pixel value of 255=white, and 0=black). Here is the function for obtaining the new pixel value:

```
int utility::windowAverage (image &src, int x, int y, int window_size)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int avg;
    for(int i = x-(window_size/2); i < x+(window_size/2);++i)
    {
        for(int j = y-(window_size/2); j < y+(window_size/2);++j)
        {
            sum += src.getPixel(i,j);
        }
    }

    avg = sum/(window_size*window_size);
    return avg;
}
```

The parameter `image &src` is the source image, and the function `src.getPixel(i,j)` returns an integer from 0 to 255 representing the brightness of the pixel at the specified coordinates (i,j).

I am running the code over gray-level images of the .pgm format.

How can I smooth the image while maintaining the same brightness?

Comment: It's likely that your `int`s overflow. Consider using `size_t` or similar for your sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not actually adding the pixels in a window with the dimension of windows_size*windows_size, but you are missing the last pixel in each dimension when computing `sum`.

You can fix this by using `<=`instead of `<`in both of your for loops.

---

**Example** of what is going wrong for `window_size = 3` and `x=0` and `y=0`:

The integer division by 2 in your for loops is floored, which means that your loops would become `for (int i=-1; i < 1; i++)`. This obviously only loops over the (two) pixles -1 and 0 in the given direction, but you still divide by the full `window_size` of 3, which makes the image darker (in this case by one third if it has constant color values).

Comment: That seems to have fixed the issue. Thanks a bunch!!